# How to calculate sum of tree branches using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, binary-tree

I am currently practicing python and I am having an issue with binary tree. I think I am fairly good in python but I am having a hard time with binary trees.

The problem is:
[image: Problem]

The first line of the function definition is given so I need to use it as is, however not sure how to calculate sum of branches.

```
def solution(arr):
    root = arr[0]

   for i in arr.index(i):
       left = sum(arr[i]-arr[0])
       right = sum(arr[i+1]-arr[0])

   if left > right:
       return "Left"

   elif left < right:
        return "Right"

   else:
       return ""
```

The error I get is

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usercode/file.py", line 36, in <module>
    test()
  File "/usercode/file.py", line 34, in test
    json.dumps(solution(*input), separators=(',', ':')))
  File "/usercode/file.py", line 5, in solution
    for i in arr.index(i):
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: You need to make a [mre]. Consider what @Engineero said, and note that the code you provided isn't properly indented.

Comment: I fixed it. It is properly indented in my IDE but when I copied and pasted it, it got messed up. I forgot to add the .index() method in the code. Also this error message is from the online IDE of the website.

Comment: Still not sure how to solve this, any tip would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are getting that error because you haven't defined `i` before you use it in `arr.index(i)`. What are you trying to do in this line?

Comment: Please fix the indentation, as Python is very sensitive to it. We can't be sure we're properly reproducing your problem if we have to fix your code ourselves before we can even run it.

Comment: I would like to use i as iterator to go over the array indexes so that odd indexes are assigned to left and even indexes are assigned to right. This is my idea but not sure how to implement it @Engineero

Comment: @glibdud I fixed it. Not sure what is the problem now?

Comment: Copy the code from this post, paste it into a file, and try to run it. You should always do that before committing your post.

Comment: @glibdud I did, and I posted the error message I got. I really don't know what the issue is. Please help

Comment: Try `for i in range(len(arr))` instead of your `arr.index(i)` line. You can't use `i` before you've defined what it is, which is why you are getting that error. This should clear up the error, but I'm not sure it will give you a correct algorithm. Should help you move forward though.

Comment: @Engineero I just tried that. Unfortunately, still doesn't work. Not sure how to fix my program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion method to find the solution.

Following is the solution code. You can [see complete code here](https://ideone.com/Gz3PA9):

```
class TreeNode:

    def __init__(self, lValue, lLeft=None, lRight=None):
        self.Value = lValue
        self.Left = lLeft
        self.Right = lRight


def addNode(root, lVal):
    newNode = TreeNode(lVal)
    queue = []
    queue.append(root)
    while(len(queue) > 0):
        node = queue.pop(0)
        if node.Left is None:
            node.Left = newNode
            break

        if node.Right is None:
            node.Right = newNode
            break

        queue.append(node.Left)
        queue.append(node.Right)


def createBinaryTree(lList):
    binaryTree = None
    for i in lList:
        if i is not -1:
            if binaryTree is not None:
                addNode(binaryTree, i)
            else:
                binaryTree = TreeNode(i)

    return binaryTree


def sum(node):
    if node is None:
        return 0
    lLeftVal = sum(node.Left)
    lRightVal = sum(node.Right)

    return (lLeftVal + lRightVal + node.Value)


def solution(binaryTree):
    if binaryTree == None:
        return ""

    if( sum(binaryTree.Left) > sum(binaryTree.Right) ):
        return "Left"
    else:
        return "Right"


def main():
    binaryTree = createBinaryTree([3,6,2,9,-1,10])
    print(solution(binaryTree))


main()
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! This sounds very complicated to me as I am still a beginner but I will go over it and try to understand
Thank you again!

Comment: I already upvoted it but it doesn't show because my reputation score is not high enough. Also I have a question, would this code work if provided with an array?
The problem states an array and I know that a binaryTree is a different structure. Would it still work if change all binary trees to array?